# GameCenter Multiplayer Stuck on "Starting Game..."

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center, multiplayer

I am currently working on my game and I have decided to enable multiplayer via GameCenter in the Game to allow users to play their friend. I have followed a tutorial by [RayWinderLinch](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1), but ran into a problem.

My problem is that when I load up the `GKMatchMakingViewController` and hit the big `Play Now` button on both devices it will find each other (which is meant to happen) and under the set game center user name it will say `Ready`.

This means that GameCenter has found each player and is ready to start the match which it should, but in my case the match never begins. It is stuck on a loop that says `Starting Game...` and nothing happens. It appears that the

`func matchmakerViewController(viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController!, didFindMatch theMatch: GKMatch!)`

and the

`func match(theMatch: GKMatch!, player playerID: String!, didChangeState state: GKPlayerConnectionState)`

method's are never ran. I am completely lost on what is going on. I have tried this many times over and over to fix the problem but nothing worked. I will attach an image that show's the screen of the application where my problem persists and I will also attach the code I am using.

> I am using a framework based of of the `GameKitHelper.h` In the
>   mentioned tutorial above. It is written in swift and is called
>   [GCHelper](https://github.com/jackcook/GCHelper)

***Code***

*The code for GCHelper can be found using the GitHub link mention earlier*

> I have cut out code that is unnecessary for this problem

```
 class GameScene : SKScene, GameKitHelper, MultiplayerNetworkingProtocol {

     override func didMoveToView () {

          GCHelper().authenticateLocalUser() //Authenticate GameCenter User
          println("\n \n \n Authenticating local user \n \n \n")

     }

      func startMultiplayer () {

           var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
           GameKitHelper().findMatchWithMinPlayers(2, maxPlayers: 2, viewController: vc!, delegate: self); //Find match and load GKMatchMakerViewController

      }

       func matchStarted() {

           //Delegate method
           println("match started")

       }

       func matchEnded() {

           //Delegate method
           println("match ended")

       }

        func match(match: GKMatch, didReceiveData: NSData, fromPlayer: String){
        //Delegate Method
        println("Did receive data")

}


     override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

         for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)


        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == multiplayer //SKSpriteNode {

             //User clicked on multiplayer button, launch multiplayer now!
             println("Loading multiplayer")
             startMultiplayer()
      }

 }
```

***Image***

[image: Game center finds each player and is ready to start the match but then it get's stuck on Starting Game...]

> UPDATE

I have noticed that when I test using my iPhone and the simulator, on the iPhone the status will go from `Ready` to `Disconnected` but on the simulator the status is still `Ready` and then I will get the following message in the console for the iPhone

> Warning matchmakerViewController:didFindMatch: delegate method not implemented`

Even though it is implemented in the `GCHelper.swift` file. This does not happen when I test on my iPhone and iPad Mini it just keeps on saying `Starting Game...`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the Game Center delegates to self/controller? I found Game Center rather buggy on the simulator, so I always use real devices for testing

Comment: I don't have a clear understanding of what you mentioned, I also tried testing on real devices too

Comment: You need to implement the `didFindMatch` - in that method you can dismiss the matchmaker viewcontroller

Comment: It is implemented in the GCHelper class as mentioned in the post

Comment: But in your `startMultiplayer()` your setting the delegate to `self` - so it expects that the methods are implemented in your class, not the GCHelper.

Comment: The bounty expried yesterday I believe but thank you for your answer

Comment: You are welcome. It was an educative research. Yet it appears, according to time stamps, that I  `answered 2 days ago`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prerequisites

- Both players must be in the same environment (*Sandbox* for testing)
- The `authenticationChanged` in `GCHelper.swift` **must not** be `private`. You may have to remove that keyword.

[image: Sandbox Player]

There are a few delegates involved, and in your example, there are a few competing protocols. *My recommendation is to create a new App using minimalistic code to track down the `startMultiplayer` issue.*

### Gamekit Multi Player Step by Step Tutorial using GCHelper

Create a new project *(Xcode > File > New > Project... > Single View Application > ... > Create)* using the very same **Product Name** & **Organization Name** as your game, so that it matches both *App Bundle Identifier* and *iTunes Game Center parameters*. This will allow you to run tests without overhead.

**Use this Podfile:**

```rb
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'SO-31699439' do
pod 'GCHelper'
end
```

**Use a GCHelperDelegate**

Create a `UIViewController` with just the bare minimum (a *Start Multiplayer* button), and connect it to this action:

```
@IBAction func startMultiplayerAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    GCHelper.sharedInstance.findMatchWithMinPlayers(
        2,
        maxPlayers: 2,
        viewController: self,
        delegate: self);
}
```

Here is the crux: the delegate you pass **must** adopt `GCHelperDelegate`. It does not have to be the same class, but in your example above it is, and the present rule was not respected. For this example, `ViewController` adopts `GCHelperDelegate`:

```
import UIKit
import GCHelper
import GameKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GCHelper.sharedInstance.authenticateLocalUser()
    }
}
```

**Implement required GCHelperDelegate methods in an `extension`**

Since `ViewController` adopts `GCHelperDelegate`, the three methods below must be in that same class, and **will** be invoked:

```
extension ViewController: GCHelperDelegate {
    func matchStarted() {
        print("matchStarted")
    }

    func match(_ match: GKMatch, didReceiveData: Data, fromPlayer: String) {
        print("match:\(match) didReceiveData: fromPlayer:\(fromPlayer)")
    }

    func matchEnded() {
        print("matchEnded")
    }
}
```

---

### Execution

*Tested: built, linked, ran, successful match.*

Launch app, tap *Start Multiplayer* button, tap Play Now on both devices (or iPhone Simulator + real device).

[image: Play now]

**Log:**

```
Authenticating local user...
Authentication changed: player not authenticated

Ready to start match!
Found player: SandboxPlayer
matchStarted
```

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-31699439) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-31699439).

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your responce! But when I tried to install the pod file I got a message from terminal saying `[!] Unable to find a target named SO-31699439` So I am wondering if there's anything wrong I am doing, I copied the exact code from the podfile above. Thanks